# logout specific session Id in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

in spring security:

i think with tow way logout called: when a session timeout occurred or a user logout itself... 

anyway in these ways , destroyedSession called in `HttpSessionEventPublisher` and `SessionRegistry` remove `SessionInformation` from sessionIds list...

when i use below method for force logout specific user , this method just "expired" `SessionInformation` in `SessionRegistry`. now when i get all online user "getAllPrincipals()" from `SessionRegistry`, the user that session expired, is in the list!

```
@Override
public  boolean forceLogOut(int userId){
    for (Object username: sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
        User temp = (User) username;
        if(temp.getId().equals(userId)){
            for (SessionInformation session : sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(username, false)) {
                session.expireNow();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

how can i logout 'specific user' or 'sessionId' that session object remove from "Web Server" and "Session Registry" ?

 i googling and found `HttpSessionContext` in Servlet API that can get HttpSession from specific sessionId. and then invalidate session. but i think this method is not completely useful! 

(note. this class is deprecated!)

what is the best way? Whether I'm wrong?

Comment: sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(sessionId).expireNow(); Spring will mark this session to be expired. Any further request from this session will invoke logout.

Comment: this is true, but if user don't not send any request and session timeout is max than 1 hour (timeout is not fire), then, when use `getAllPrincipals()` , this method return all principles include both online session and expire session...this is my problem...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){    
            //new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
            persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.logout(request, response, auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }
```

To  logout specific session Id check that link:
[how to log a user out programmatically using spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370819/how-to-log-a-user-out-programmatically-using-spring-security)

Comment: thanks for response...i wanna force logout one user with another user and then immediately remove session object of user from `SessionRegistry` and my Web Server..i think this method logout user with itself.!

Comment: do you have an idea what should I do? i wanna manage online user and after force logout one user see online user.when i use `getAllPrincipals()` , expired session is in the list...!

Comment: i see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22381765/5267531).. thanks for attempt...i must use `session.expireNow();` and `sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(info.getSessionId());` together..but session not deleted from Web Server until client send an request or timeout fired...!

Comment: welcome :p .. you can accept it as valid answer if your problem is resolved

Comment: if i ignore Web Server problem this answer is valid :D...anyway thanks for helping...maybe i can not delete session from Web Server...i don't know..!

Comment: after test..i used `sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(info.getSessionId());` and `session.expireNow();` together. but is not working and user don't force logout..! it is not true to use these method together for force logout..!