# How to remove existing sessions by specific principal name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, redis, spring-session

I'm using Spring Session 1.3.0 with Redis backend in my project.

I have an use case that the super admin might update the roles of existing user who might already logged in. I want to delete the existing session records for those users after changing their roles.

Is there API of Spring Session to archive it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also work out another way to clean sessions of specific user,

```
@Autowired
FindByIndexNameSessionRepository sessionRepository;

sessionRepository.findByIndexNameAndIndexValue(FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME,
                username).keySet().forEach(session -> sessionRepository.delete((String) session));
```

Comment: Deleting sessions prematurely  has some side effects if you allow multiple sessions of a single user. Have a look on this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370819/how-to-log-a-user-out-programmatically-using-spring-security

Comment: @mirmdasif it's an interesting finding. I'm wondering why spring/spring security still gives the permission of request with invalid session id(expired or removed).

Answer (score 7):

```
    @Autowired
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    public void expireUserSessions(String username) {
        for (Object principal : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
            if (principal instanceof User) {
                UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
                if (userDetails.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                    for (SessionInformation information : sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(userDetails, true)) {
                        information.expireNow();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```